# Checking if object has property with given name returns false

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I have this simple code:

```js
let obj = {
    games: [
        {id: 'test'}
    ]
}

console.log(obj.games[0].id) // returns: test
console.log('games[0].id' in obj) // returns: false
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('games[0].id')) // returns: false
```

I don't understand the return value when I try to check for its property name instead of returning its property value.

Comment: It's not a single property? Your object would have to look like this: `{"games[0].id": 'test' }`

Comment: console.log(obj.games[0].hasOwnProperty('id')) // returns: true nedsting not allowed in hasOwnProperty()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three objects and the methods you are using to test are meant for a single object.

- `obj` - object containing a games property
- `obj.games` - array with one element
- `obj.games[0]` - object with id property

Consider these which all are true:

```
let obj = {
    games: [
        {id: 'test'}
    ]
}

console.log(`obj.hasOwnProperty('games')`, obj.hasOwnProperty('games'))
console.log(`'games' in obj`, 'games' in obj)

console.log(`obj.games.hasOwnProperty('0')`, obj.games.hasOwnProperty('0'))
console.log(`'0' in obj.games`, '0' in obj.games)

console.log(`obj.games[0].hasOwnProperty('id')`, obj.games[0].hasOwnProperty('id'))
console.log(`'id' in obj.games[0]`, 'id' in obj.games[0])

if (obj && obj.games && obj.games.length > 0 && obj.games[0].id) {
  console.log('obj.games has at least one element, '
       + 'and the first element has an id')
}


let id = obj && obj.games && obj.games.length > 0 && obj.games[0].id;
console.log('id:', id);
```

Answer (score 0):

`in` and `hasOwnProperty()` just take a single property name, they don't accept an expression with nested properties.

So you have to test each level separately.

```
console.log('games' in obj && 0 in obj.games && "id" in obj.games[0])
```

You can also use optional chaining to combine all but the last check.

```
console.log(obj?.games.?[0] && "id" in obj.games[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator can only test a single attribute. It's not intelligent enough to follow a path.

You could just

```
const value = obj?.games?.[0]?.id;
const exists = value !== undefined;
console.log(exists)
```

More importantly, in this case you really shouldn't use the `in` operator at all. The disadvantage of the `in` operator, is that it requires the tested field to be coded as a string.

In general putting the names of fields in strings is something to avoid, because it makes it harder to find usages and to refacture code later on.

The use of the `in` operator can only be justified if the name of the tested field is not a constant, not known in advance.

---

Having said that, the `hasOwnProperty` function does something slightly different. It is actually more strict than the solution presented above, and also more strict than the `in` operator. It strictly checks for fields on the object itself, not the ones of super/base types.

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns true if the specified property is
> a direct property of the object — even if the value is null or
> undefined. The method returns false if the property is inherited, or
> has not been declared at all. Unlike the in operator, this method does
> not check for the specified property in the object's prototype chain. *(source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty))*